# Best way to display view that includes many other views in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created view `AddonPickerControl` that is a horizontal `StackLayout` with `AddonControls`. The problem is that Pages that includes `AddonPickerListView` loads about 2sec, its too long.

I have tried to achive same result with binding addons to a `ListView`, but the problem is that each cell have to have a counter that describes how much specific addon has been picked. I have no Idea how to do this in `ViewCell`, so I decided to `StackLayout`.

```
public partial class AddonPickerControl : ContentView
{
    public AddonPickerControl (AddonPicker addonPicker)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        _addonPicker = addonPicker;
        BindingContext = _addonPicker;
    }

    private readonly AddonPicker _addonPicker;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        foreach (var addon in _addonPicker.AvailableAddons)
        {
            var addonControl = new AddonControl(addon);
            addonControl.AddonPicked += OnAddonPicked;

            AddonContainer.Children.Add(addonControl);
        }
    }
        ...
}


public partial class AddonControl : ContentView
{
    public AddonControl (Addon addon)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        _addon = addon;
        this.BindingContext = _addon;
    }

    private readonly Addon _addon;
        ...
}
```

How should I display an `AddonPickerControl`? Filling `StackLayout` with other views takes too much time. Or maybe it is possible to create a `ViewCell` that will have a counter that describes how much binded addon has been picked.

Comment: A `ViewCell` can have a `StackLayout` inside of it, or a ContentView, or any container view like a `Grid`, `AbsoluteLayout`, etc.

Comment: I know, but can it have its own logic? For example Can a view cell have Button "+", Button "-" and Label thats a counter?

Comment: @BartekChyży Sure, you can customize your ViewCell. [customizing-cell-appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can have buttons in every item in a list view to update a count for that item.

First, here is a simple list view with a view cell with 3 labels and two buttons:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                    <Label Text="Count:" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Count}" />
                    <Button Text="+" Command="{Binding BtnClickPlusCommand}"  />
                    <Button Text="-" Command="{Binding BtnClickMinusCommand}"  />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
        {
            Item item = new Item { ItemName = $"Item {i}", Count = "5" };
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        BindingContext = this;
    }

}
```

And the `Item` class which will have your click handlers and is a simple view model as it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    int _count;
    public ICommand BtnClickPlusCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand BtnClickMinusCommand { get; private set; }

    public Item()
    {
        BtnClickPlusCommand = new Command(btnClickPlus);
        BtnClickMinusCommand = new Command(btnClickMinus);
    }

    void btnClickPlus()
    {
        Count = (++_count).ToString();
    }

    void btnClickMinus()
    {
        Count = (--_count).ToString();
    }

    public string Count 
    {
        get
        {
            return _count.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            int j;
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out j))
            {
                _count = j;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("value could not be parsed to int");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

So, in this case we have essentially created a view model for each item so we can have the command that will handle the button click in the actual Item object that is associated with the button, so we just have to update the count. And using bindings, the UI is updated automatically with the new count. The results:

[image]